# Make Pole Targets follow the bone

Tags: rigging, inverse-kinematics

Im trying to rig a Humanoid in blender, and I have the Iks done with their Pole Targets. My problem its that I dont know what its the best option to make them follow their bone position.

I have tried copying location , but its not a option since i cant move the bone. I tried parenting it to the ik or the bones too, but the result its very bad. Any help?

The first image is the bones in rest position.

The second one its if I move the Ik controller.

The third its if I parent it to the bones.

[image: The bones in rest pose]

[image: The bone wont move]

[image: If I parent it]

Comment: I think it's better you have an extra bone to be the IK and you can parent the Pole to the Foot.

Comment: What do you mean? An extra bone between the sections of the finger?

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice that was a hand.

Comment: You can duplicate that IK bone and make it the parent of the Pole bone.

Comment: The IK bone its the right one in the first image, the pole bone the middle one. So I duplicate the right one and this is the parent of the bone? Why cant i parent the pole one to the IK then? (I dont do that because the result its bad)